# input value to object and then that object push to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

Hollow i have some issue and small problem
i have 3 input fields I need to get values on click from them assign them to object and that object push in to array
can somebody can help ore say where to look info I'm searching on MDN but I can't find correct topic whit examples
1)input value to object and then that object push to array

```js
function $(e) {
  return document.querySelector(e);
}

function $$(e) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(e);
}

var startBtn = $("send");

startBtn.addEventListener('click', creatTask, false);

function creatTask() {

  var addTaskName = $(".task-name"),
    addCategory = $(".category"),
    addTaskSatus = $(".status");


  <!--    task.Taskname = addTaskName.value
  task.Category = addCategory.value
  task.Status = addTaskSatus.value........... ? -- >

    var TaskListArray = [];

  var task = {
    Taskname: undefined,
    Category: undefined,
    Status: undefined
  }
  console.log(task)

}

document.write("message")
```

[Link to jsfiddle with html and javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/Guntarwi/yc4d2x9h/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `id` or `className` selector at `var startBtn = $("send")`; defining `TaskListArray` outside of `creatTask` function; setting values directly at creation of `task` object; use `Array.prototype.push()` to add current `task` object to `TaskListArray` array.

Also, use `window.onload` event, or place `<script>` after elements in `html` for elements queried in `DOM` to be loaded in `document` before `creatTask` is called or `startBtn` defined

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
      function $(e) {
        return document.querySelector(e);
      }

      function $$(e) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(e);
      }

      var startBtn = $(".send");

      var TaskListArray = [];

      startBtn.addEventListener('click', creatTask, false);

      function creatTask() {

        var addTaskName = $(".task-name"),
          addCategory = $(".category"),
          addTaskSatus = $(".status");

        var task = {
          Taskname: addTaskName.value,
          Category: addCategory.value,
          Status: addTaskSatus.value
        }

        TaskListArray.push(task)
        console.log(task)

      }
    }
    // document.write("message")
</script>
<input class="task-name" name="task" />
<br>
<input class="category" name="category" />
<br>
<input class="status" name="status" />
<br>
<input type="button" class="send" value="send" />
```